# Fragment wont start - called from Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I'm trying to start a fragment from my main activity, but somehow the fragment is not showing up. Can someone help me with this?

Here is my code:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_menu);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.action_menu){
            Log.d("--", "menu clicked");
            MenuFragment newFragment = new MenuFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack
            transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }


}
```

main activity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_rl" >

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/action_menu" android:text="Menu"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and my fragment Class:

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment{
    final String TAG=this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    private GridView grid;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mView;
        Log.d(TAG, "Hello from Fragment");
        mView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fullscreen, null);
        initWidgets(mView);

        return mView;
    }

    private void initWidgets(View mView) {
        grid=(GridView) mView.findViewById(R.id.menu_fullscreen_grid);

    }



}
```

Comment: Please Read [Developer Documents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), This is not how we can use fragment.

Comment: Use FragmentActivity instead of Activity to show Fragment

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK trying it right now..

Comment: See if this example helps: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/Demonstrateshowfragmentscanparticipateintheoptionsmenu.htm

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK IT works thanks - when you just submit your answer!

Answer (score 0):

you cannot replace what you put in  setContentView(R.layout.main); if main.xml is hardCoded...(xml file). with 
transaction.replace...
You may use fragmentActivity without setContentView(R.layout.main)

Comment: He could have an empty `FrameLayout` with a specific ID as a container and just replace the content of that framelayout with a fragment transaction: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace